# Percentage between two numbers in Reactjs

Tags: javascript

I need to find out percentage between two arrays, by comparing its similarities value. For example, I have two arrays.

```
const arrOne = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
const arrTwo = ["one", "three", "four"];

let percentage = 100 * Math.abs(
            (arrOne.length - arrTwo.length) /
              ((arrOne.length + arrTwo.length) / 2)
          )
```

I need to Compare this two arrays and need to find the percentage of this based on the similar strings. The Above method is, what i tried, but didn't get expected output

Comment: How would you do it "by hand"? You'd probably see how much of one array is contained in the other. As far as a "percentage" goes, it's unclear what you mean by that since there are no criteria provided in the question.

Comment: You can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for that. [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) arrTwo to a number of matches.

Comment: This code does (something) with sizes--it doesn't take into account any content whatsoever. I don't know what output you expected (since you don't say), but your own problem statement clearly indicates that doing something based purely on size is pointless. Maybe take a stab at the actual problem first.

Comment: I want to get percetage as output by comparing this two arrays. Like, if both array has three strings. In that, If One string is same in both array. Then,  i am expecting an 33.33% as output @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
const arrTwoInArrOneRatio = arrTwo.filter(i=>arrOne.includes(i)).length / arrOne.length
const arrOneInArrTwoRatio = arrOne.filter(i=>arrTwo.includes(i)).length / arrTwo.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the overlapping ratio between the two arrays:

```
function intersectionRatio(arrOne, arrTwo){
    intersection = arrOne.filter(el => arrTwo.includes(el))
    elementsCount = arrOne.length + arrTwo.length - intersection.length
    return intersection.length / elementsCount
}

intersectionRatio([1,2,3], [4,5,6]); // 0
intersectionRatio([1,2,3], [1,2,3]); // 1
intersectionRatio([1,2,3], [2,3,4]); // 0.5
```